# Retain TempData Value after creating new session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session-variables

For some reason, I am creating new Session within my controller's action method. But I have TempData in my ActionMethod1 and I would like to pass the value to ActionMethod2 after creating new seesion. But after creating new session id my TempData value cleared. Below code has been used to create new sessionid.

```
System.Web.SessionState.SessionIDManager manager = new     
System.Web.SessionState.SessionIDManager();
string NewSession = manager.CreateSessionID(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
```

Please let me know if any other possible solutions to retain tempdata value even after creating new session.

Comment: What about storing the TempData values in a variable, create the new session and write those values back into the TempData dictionary within the same method?

Answer (score 0):

> But after creating new session id my TempData value cleared.

TempData is stored in the session state.  This is why the values are deleted.

> Please let me know if any other possible solutions to retain tempdata value even after creating new session.

You should be able to do something like the following (untested):

```
var oldTempData = TempData.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);

System.Web.SessionState.SessionIDManager manager = new     
  System.Web.SessionState.SessionIDManager();
string NewSession = manager.CreateSessionID(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);

foreach(var kvp in oldTempData)
  TempData.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
```